# Javascript : Detect if a String contain url image

Tags: javascript, regex, parsing

I have the following String :

```
var str = "Hello, i would like to show this image : http://logonoid.com/images/stack-overflow-logo.png" ;
```

I would like to create a function **which detect the presence of image urls and return a 2 things :**

- The new String without the image url
- An array containing image url found in the String.

How can i do that ?

Comment: Have you tried anything? Look at [`String.prototype.match()`](https://devdocs.io/javascript/global_objects/string/match)

Comment: Is the url pattern fixed as you have posted here **some text then url**?

Comment: no, the url of image can be everywhere in the string

Comment: Yes, you can do that with a regular expression. I see you added a tag for that but you forgot to add why you think it can be done.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this, i am checking for an image file extension

```
var str = "Hello, i would like to show this image : http://logonoid.com/images/stack-overflow-logo.gif" ;
var test = (/\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|tiff|png)$/i).test(str)
```

if it finds a match it will return `true` otherwise `false`

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fgttr7sa/)

Answer (score 0):

Are you familiar with regular expressions? Because the things you ask are pretty easy:
the regex to detect an URL is

```
^(http|https)://
```

and in Javascript that would be:

```
str.match(^(http|https)://);
```

Now it is up to you to find out how to save the correct output.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following to match:

```
(https?:[^\s]+)
```

- Group 1 will give the list of urls.. you can replace them with `''` empty string to get the new string.

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/yE4yT4/9)

Answer (score 0):

Simple way could looks like that

```
var str = "Hello, i would like to show this image : http://logonoid.com/images/stack-overflow-logo.png" ;
console.log(str.includes(":"));


if(str.includes(":") && ( (str.includes("http") || str.includes("https")) )){
  var newOutput = str.split(":");
  for(var i in newOutput){
  console.log("[" + i + "]: " + newOutput[i]);
  }

  var message= newOutput[0];
  var urlImage= newOutput[1] + newOutput[2];

  console.log("message: " + message +" , URL: " + urlImage);
}else{
 console.log("no URL find");
}
```

You can use match for that "if" and it will looks better :o)

Answer (score 0):

Shortest way to do it I think:

```
console.log(newVal.match(/\.(jpeg|jpg|png|gif)/g) != null);
```

if it finds a match it will return **true** otherwise **false**